# MYSQL error when I run the query: The total number of locks exceeds the lock table size

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to create table in MySQL. One of the queries involves create and inserting a large amount of rows into a temp table. When I try to run it, I get this error:

Error code 1206: The number of locks exceeds the lock table size.

Please help me how to resolve this.

Comment: Please provide some more details of what you're trying to do. Specifically, number of rows to insert, why you're putting it in a temporary table, what method you're using to do this, etc.

Comment: Post the query so we can have a clue what you are trying to do.  Number of rows you hope to insert.  Error log content after failure - last 200 lines from your error.log.  SELECT @@log_error; to determine error log filename.  If you do not have an error log, blessings to you.

Comment: How much RAM do you have?  Are you familiar with changing your my.cnf or my.ini configuration file?  Could you post TEXT results of SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE '%size'; ?